# ambiguity of どうこう

Tags: homonyms

Perhaps one of the more interesting/infuriating things i've found is how どうこう is seemingly always written without kanji...

the obvious ones with  する default to 同行 I assume

> だからと言って今すぐどうこうするって話でもないけど。-just cuz i said that doesn't mean i saying i want to go out with her

同好

> 一概にどうこう言えない気がするんだけど…… - I feel like you can’t say all (girls ) have
>   the same tastes (when it comes to guy's heights)

"[どうのこうの](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1477900054)"

> 「なんでせっかく好きな人と結ばれたのに、他人がどうこう言って間に割り込んでこようとするわけ……？　関係ないじゃん……」- how come even though i'm finally with a guy i like, other people keep disturbing us and saying all this crap, what we're doing has nothing to do with them.

and the stuff I'm not so sure of

どうのこうの or 動向？

> 俺が殴られるどうこうはもう関係ない。- your ("tendency" to assault me/this and that sort of beating me up) is already irrelevant ?

動向?

> お前がどうこうじゃなく俺が決めたんだ。(context is "っ…入れてくださいっ！ 　私なら大丈夫です。これしき耐えられます" )
>   - I , who "doesn't have the same "tendencies" as you, has already made up my mind. - really not sure about the last one.

Appreciate any clarifications and further insight

Comment: All of your examples are not 同行, 同好 nor 動向. If you really need to write them in Kanji, use 如何斯う. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/155649/meaning/m0u/

Comment: Literally all of them are the "如何の斯うの" どうこう? even for the 同好 sentence where they're talking about how girls think about height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all your five example sentences, どうこう is [this どうこう](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%86) meaning "this and that", "something", "blah-blah", etc. It's used to contract the unimportant part of the sentence. It's interchangeable with どうのこうの.

どうこう can work as an adverb, "(like) this or that":

> 今すぐどうこうするって話でもないけど。
>   That does not mean I'll do something (about the problem) right away.
>
> 一概にどうこう言えない気がする。
>   I feel we cannot say something sweepingly. / It's not a black-and-white situation.

どうこう also can colloquially form a noun clause (i.e., どうこう can be followed by particles like が, を, の):

> [俺が殴られるどうこう]はもう関係ない。
>   I'll be beaten, or this, or that...they're no longer relevant.
>
> [お前がどうこう]じゃなく俺が決めたんだ。
>   This is not a you-think-this-or-that kind of problem; *I* decided it.
>
> 彼とどうのこうのの前に自分を磨きなさい。
>   Before thinking about doing something with him, you must make yourself a better person.
>
> <sup>(Forgive me if my English translations are unnatural; I'm bad at this type of colloquial sentences)</sup>

Unsurprisingly, 動向, 同行 and 同好 are normally written in kanji. These words are simply not used in your examples.

Comment: i see thanks, if i didn't know better i would have thought some of the kanji version fit better

Comment: @charu I'm not sure my English sentences are okay (especially the last three). Now that you know the essence of どうこう, please feel free to correct them. Thank you.

Comment: You got the point across extremely clearly which is more important imo :)

Answer (score 2):

どうこう, just like どうのこうの are adverbs. 
When used in negative sentences, they mean "anything".

Examples:
私がどうこう言える問題ではない。
This is a problem I can't say anything.

そのことについてどうこう言える立場ではない
I am not in a position to say anything on the matter.

どうこうするうちに事態は悪化した
In the meantime, the situation grew more serious.

どうこう【如何斯う】
［副］《副詞「どう」に副詞「こう」の付いた語》
多く否定表現に用いて、特にそれと定めず、さまざまな行為や事態をひっくるめて指し示す。どうのこうの。とやかく。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/155649/meaning/m1u/どうこう/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/155649/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%86/)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/どうこう/#je-53009](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%86/#je-53009)

どうのこうの: いろいろ言い立てるさま。なんのかの。どうこう。

Examples:
どうのこうの言ってもはじまらない。
No matter what you say, it will not start.

どうのこうのと うるさく 言うな。
Stop nagging.

このことについてはどうのこうの言う権利はない。
I have no right to say anything about the matter.

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/どうのこうの/#je-53470](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE/#je-53470)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/156614/meaning/m1u/どうのこうの/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/156614/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE/)

Comment: どこからどこまでが辞書からの引用ですか？　引用箇所は分かるように示（以下省略）