# What is the meaning of どうの?

Tags: meaning, words, usage, word-usage

Context: a former swordsman takes his daughter to attend kendo lessons. She doesn't seem happy, so he reminds her that she decided herself to go, at which che replies:

> んだよ！とーさんがさんざん剣が**どうの**って話ばっかするからだろ！！

What is the meaning of どうの? I found an example on Kenkyusha dictionary suggesting it can be used in lists:

> 色が**どうの**デザインが**どうの**と彼女は文句ばかりつけている.
>
> She's forever complaining; if it isn't the color, it's the design or something else.

Is this the way it was used in my sentence? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as どうこう or どうのこうの explained in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61932/5010). It replaces a (subjectively) unimportant part of the sentence like "blah blah". In this case, the father has told her a long story about 剣, but she is thinking what he said was unimportant to her.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently どうの is short for どうのこうの which means "this and that", "to keep talking incessantly about something", "to keep complaining".
In negative sentences it means "anything".

Examples from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE/#je-53470):

> どうのこうのとうるさく言うな。
>   Stop nagging.
>   このことについてはどうのこうの言う権利はない。
>   I have no right to say anything about the matter.

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/どうの/#je-53469](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE/#je-53469)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/どうのこうの/#je-53470](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE/#je-53470)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/156614/meaning/m0u/どうの/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/156614/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE/)